# How do i send webhook data and turn it into a CSV file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, export-to-csv, algorithmic-trading

I'm a little new to coding but I'd like to know how I can get webhook data from say tradingview and just turn the info into a csv. I use python

edit: ok hi i figured how i want to do my app. i am stuck again but with a more descriptive image

id like to figure out how to turn my current request into a csv file i can place into a path of my choice in my computer. Below is my current code but ill editing it

[my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt675.png)

things to note is that i am using aws chalice as a rest api to get webhook requests from. My goal is to turn that webhook data into a csv file.

example json: { "name": "kaishi",
"lotsize": "0.03",
"Signal": "op_sell"
}
these signals do change so the request is always different

in the image i posted i do get a error from my powershell that i dont understand because as ive said i am quite new to coding.

(  raise TypeError('Object of type %s is not JSON serializable'
TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable

raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index)

thats just 2 error2, they vary depending on how im testing my app.

### any info would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Webhooks are requests that are sent from the remote server (in this case the "tradingview" server) to your server, so you'll need to find an existing package that handles webhooks from "tradingview" and deploy it accordingly, or develop with one of the many web service frameworks exposed through Python. A good place to start is exploring some of the open-source options available on GitHub: https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=tradingview&type=Repositories